# How to increase the titelBar Height?

Tags: ios4, titlebar

How can I increase the height of a `titleBar` ?

Comment: What do you mean with title bar ? And in the title of your question you say "width", in the body of the question you "height". Which one is it ?

Comment: sorry i made mistake while typing...can you help me with this?I want to increase the height of my titleBar.I am making a browser and need to show url in a label...and UITextbox below that.so i need to increase the height...

Comment: You can always edit your question to add more detail. So, title bar of *what* ? Title bar of a UINavigationBar or something ?

Comment: yes titleBar of a NavigaitonBar...

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, but it should work like this: In your UIViewController's `viewDidLoad` method, do this:

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
frame.size.height = 123;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:frame];
```

**Edit:** According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385538/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-the-uinavigationbar-in-an-iphone-app) it looks like you cannot change the height of a UINavigationBar at all.

Comment: i don't want to change it problematically.How can i do it from the UI?I mean like dragging

Comment: You mean in Interface Builder ? You can't. Try it, the height field is greyed out. You can only change it with code.

Comment: Yeah, no wonder... according to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385538/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-the-uinavigationbar-in-an-iphone-app), it looks like you simply can't change the height at all.