# UINavigationBar bar height is not changing

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a custom UINavigationController which I Simply resize the height but I get no result:
[image]

actually my main code is this: ( this will get perfect height according tu device size )

```
class NavigationController1: UINavigationController {

let Theframe = UIScreen.main.bounds

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.navigationBar.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.navigationBar.frame.origin.x*Theframe.width/375, y: self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y*Theframe.height/667, width:self.navigationBar.frame.width*Theframe.width/375, height: self.navigationBar.frame.height*Theframe.height/667)
}
}
```

but the upper code for height isn't working neither.

Comment: I think nothing has changed since this question in 2009. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385538/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-the-uinavigationbar-in-an-iphone-app#1385643. Unfortunately I think you cannot change the height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by putting in viewWillLayoutSubviews()
final code:

```
import UIKit

class NavigationController1: UINavigationController {

let Theframe = UIScreen.main.bounds

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.navigationBar.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.navigationBar.frame.origin.x, y: self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, width:self.navigationBar.frame.width, height: 200)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be override and redrawn because of the sIze inspector. Put the same requirements there so you can ensure its not overriding the custom code.

Comment: Add your desired height and width to the size inspector as well

Comment: I did, still no result